# Could not find method release() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, facebook-android-sdk

I've just updated my project to the Android Gradle plugin [0.9.0](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/SymhwQYyUUi) and I'm getting the following error trying to run my project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:                    
Build file 'C:\...\facebookSDK\build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:          
A problem occurred evaluating project ':facebookSDK'.
> Could not find method release() for arguments [build_3ug2bdgu6mi6jljp3krac916n3$_run_closure1_closure4@e1bf3ff] on project ':facebookSDK'.

* Try:                      
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I only get this error with one of my projects. If I switch back to 0.8.+ it works fine.

This is the gradle.build file of the facebookSDK module.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I'm having the same error!!! Please help!!!

Comment: @groff07 yep! check the accepted answer and also [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i'm pretty sure that `release { ... }` should be inside `buildTypes`(which should be inside `android`) not in `android`